# Apply patch to web.config in sitecore

Tags: visual-studio, sitecore8, web.config-transform

I am little new to sitecore and I got a work thats bugging me. I was given a task to applying sitecore patches to the project and deploy to Dev. There were 3 patches. I completed the first two as it was to applied in Sitecore.config file. The third patch was to add config in "appSettings" node and "assemblyBinding" node in Web.config file. When I used the traditional way of patching like I used for the first two, I was getting an error and later I found out this:
[image]

My project doesn't use slowcheetah. I researched more about this and found that I have to do web config transforms. The more I researched how to do transforms more confused I got. Below are the config that I have to insert in Web.config :

In appSetting node :
`<add key="Telerik.AsyncUpload.ConfigurationEncryptionKey" value="YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY_HERE" />`

In assemblyBinding node :

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2015.1.401.45" newVersion="2017.2.621.45" />  
      </dependentAssembly>
```

I was hoping to get a simple solution or references to articles on how to do insert these configs in web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from web.config file transformations. Transformations will allow you to have different values for different environments.There is a short and informative blog post by Martin Miles. It contains everything that is needed.

https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/how-apply-xml-transform-works-in-helix-habitat

Official Microsoft documentation has an example on how to apply transformations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Answer (score 0):

As per the Sitecore Doc, we cannot create the patch for web.config
You can refer https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/use-a-patch-file-to-customize-the-sitecore-configuration.html point 4 (Note)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4hI5.png)